# Drop Down Box not returning the Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code populating a dropdown box, it selects the current RunArea assigns it to the selected Run with **run.RunRunAreaID** but when I update the Run, the RunArea Drop Down it's not sending the ID back, so I end up with NULL

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    Run run = db.Runs.Find(id);

    ViewBag.RunAreaName = new SelectList(db.RunAreas, "ID", "RunAreaName", run.RunRunAreaID);

    return View(run);
}
```

**My View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("RunAreaName")
```

This is all done in the Run controller, the Drop Down is populated with Run Areas form a different table/Model, so One Run Area has Many Runs.

**Edit**

I have five Run Areas and they are all being passed through to the view, all five Run Areas display in the drop down box with the correct one selected for that particular Run, hence why I need **run.RunRunAreaId**. That all works fine.

But if I update/change the Run Area in the Drop Down, the view returns NULL for that field.

**Edit**

**RunArea Model**

```
public partial class RunArea
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RunAreaName { get; set; }

    public List<Run> Runs { get; set; }
}
```

**Run Model**

```
public partial class Run
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RunReportID { get; set; }
    public int RunRunAreaID { get; set; }
    public string RunName { get; set; }
    public bool RunSnowmaking { get; set; }
    public bool RunGroomed { get; set; }
    public bool RunDisplaySnowmaking { get; set; }
    public bool RunLikely { get; set; }

    public RunArea RunArea { get; set; }
}
```

Lazy loading is turned off as they are pushing out XML

Comment: Base on your current code, I assume that your dropdownlist doesnot associate with any request parameter, so it will not send its value to server. But to have a better view at the context, please show me your form as well as `Edit` which is use to update your run

Comment: Ah, should I be sending it back in the form???

Comment: I think you should create your dropdownlist as follow: `@Html.DropdownList(model => model.RunRunAreaID, ViewBag.RunAreaName)`

Comment: With this, you bind your `RunRunAreaID` to dropdownlist, and it will be submit to server along side with another data in form

Comment: Thanks Doan but I've tried all that. It's not helping that I'm doing this in MVC5 all the generated code is different.This has worked for me before!

Comment: try changing your input parameter name from `id` to `RunAreaName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

```
ViewBag.RunAreaName = new SelectList(db.RunAreas, "ID", "RunAreaName", run.RunRunAreaID);
```

In your View:

```
using (@Html.BeginForm(//add your form setting))
{
    //first parameter to set id and name for drop down list
    //second parameter bind data to it.
    @Html.DropDownList("RunRunID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RunAreaName)
    //add some other property here
}
```

Notice that I changed `ID` to `RunRunAreaID` in `ViewBag.RunAreaName`. This will bind your dropdownlist value to `Model.RunRunAreaID` when submit to server

Comment: This is the problem i'm having, this is all hapening in the Run Controller the Dropdown is populated with RunAreas so I get: **DataBinding: 'mysite.Models.RunArea' does not contain a property with the name 'RunRunAreaID'**. If I do that.

Comment: I made a modified, please take a look

Comment: Thanks Champ, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

use this in your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("RunAreaName",ViewBag.RunAreaName as SelectList,"Select Text")
```

Also in here

```
ViewBag.RunAreaName = new SelectList(db.RunAreas, "ID", "RunAreaName", run.RunRunAreaID);
```

I don't think you need `run.RunRunAreaId`

```
ViewBag.RunAreaName = new SelectList(db.RunAreas, "ID", "RunAreaName")
```

is enough